When will the vertically mirrored triangular matrix be helpful?
I encountered with this question when I encountered one matrix with the following form recently:
$$
{\displaystyle L'={\begin{bmatrix}0&&&&\ell _{1,n}\\ &&&\ell _{2,n-1}&\ell _{2,n}\\ &&\ldots &\ell _{3,n-1}&\ell _{3,n}\\  &\vdots &\ldots &\vdots &\vdots\\ \ell _{n,1}&\ell _{n,2}&\ldots &\ell _{n,n-1}&\ell _{n,n}\end{bmatrix}}}
$$
This is like lower triangular matrix but get vertically mirrored.
I know LU decomposition will make lower triangular matrix and upper triangular matrix valuable.
Maybe there exists one matrix to transform $L$ to $L'$. But temporarily I can't figure that out.
Q:
Then when will the above mirrored lower/upper triangular matrix be helpful for some transformation or application?

As for how to transform between $L$ and $L'$, you can multiply with an anti-diagonal unity matrix, $ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \
0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 \
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \
1 & \cdots & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}  $ (please imagine the diagonal dots are going the other way)

@Milten Thanks. Then 4 triangular  matrix forms are all connected.
